# Target next element with class

Tags: jquery

here is the scenario

I'm doing a parallax page and I have main div containing various `<div class="slide marker marker-1840" id="1840" data-slide="1840" ></div>`

My goal is once the waypoint function is triggered it would get the current marker at the same time retrieve the next marker. So far this is what I got.

```
var now = jQuery('.lax-wrapper').find('.marker-' + dataslide);
var now_year = jQuery('.lax-wrapper').find('.marker-' + dataslide).attr('data-slide');
var next = jQuery(now).next('.marker').attr('data-slide');
console.log(now_year+'---'+next);
```

With the current results I'm only able to get the current year but **not** the following year marker.

Would appreciate any help on what's wrong.

Here is the sample of the html.

```
<div class="lax-wrapper">
      <div class="slide marker marker-1840" id="1840" data-slide="1840" >    </div>
      <!-- HTML CONTENT -->
      <div class="slide marker marker-1860" data-slide="1860"></div>
      <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

Comment: can you show the full html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L3LjZ/ it seems to work just fine, also note that you can use .data('slide') instead of .attr('data-slide')

Comment: @Sgoldy God damn there must be something in my structure that's fcking it up.

Comment: @Tony then share the exact code and have it in a fiddle, this way we can see the error exactly as you see it.

Comment: @Sgoldy I have found the problem should I post it in the answer so people might have experienced it?

Comment: It will be good for others if you post your answer.